# Halt form submission until user agreement is accepted

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

On many websites I see the following event happening.

A user fills out a registration form and presses the submit button. After the button is pressed, a modal with user agreement terms is displayed.

How can I ensure that the form submission is halted until the user agreement terms are accepted?

Comment: If you don't find an exact step by step for your more complex problem, break it apart and solve the components individually.

Comment: If I could make it less complex, I wouldn't ask.

Comment: Here's one solution: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/4jya9rkg/ (making the modal part of the form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html#bb-confirm-dialog), it has options for confirming forms

Answer (score 1):

Try using confirm().
    example:

```
<form id="myForm">
</form>

<button type=button id="myButton">Submit </button>

<javascript>

  $("#myButton").on('click', function()){
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to submit form?')){
    $("#myForm").submit()
  }
}
</javascript>
```